# How to align spinner drop-down menu to center with spinner

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, spinner

[click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIMGa.jpg)

I need to make that dropdown popup exactly like that.
i need help with-

1. vertical and horizontal position of popup wont change
2. how to get these rounded corners.
3. popup item text won't align to center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the above requirements you can use a [Material Drop Down Menu](https://material.io/components/menus/android#using-menus) with a custom style which inherits from a parent of **Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu**.

1)First you have to declare this Material Drop Down Menu in your xml layout like below using a custom style. Note that using the attributes : **android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="0dp"** or **android:dropDownVerticalOffset="10dp"** you can move the popup menu Vertically/Horizontally with a specific amount of dp value.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropDownTextInputLayout"
        style="@style/MyExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="0dp"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="10dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="160dp"
            android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

where @style/MyExposedDropdownMenu is your custom style like below. In this style the key points is that we inherit from the parent **OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu** and we override the **boxBackgroundColor** to change the TextInputLayout Drop Down Box Colour and the custom **shapeAppearance** where you can change the corner radius of TextInputLayout.

```
    <style name="MyExposedDropdownMenu" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="endIconTint">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
        <item name="cornerSize">50dp</item>
    </style>
```

2)To make also each item in the Drop Down list to have rounded corners you can achieve this programmatically using a custom **ShapeAppearanceModel** with the attribute **CornerFamily.ROUNDED** and the rounded value in pixels. Finally to align each item in Center you have to make a custom layout with    **android:textAlignment="center"** and pass this custom layout item into your adapter.
Below is how to achieve the above tasks in code:

```
//your data
String[] items  = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7", "8","9", "10"};

//get your MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
MaterialAutoCompleteTextView mAutoCompleteTV = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

//initialize your adapter with a custom list item layout
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_drop_down_item , items);

//create your custom ShapeAppearanceModel for your Drop Down Item
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, dp2px(getResources(), 50))
        .build();

//get the current DropDownBackground
Drawable dropDownDrawable = mAutoCompleteTV.getDropDownBackground();

//and change the MaterialShapeDrawable fill Color and set your Custom ShapeAppearanceModel
if(dropDownDrawable instanceof MaterialShapeDrawable)
{
    MaterialShapeDrawable dropDownBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) dropDownDrawable;
    dropDownBackground.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, android.R.color.black));
    dropDownBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel);
}

//sets the adapter to MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
mAutoCompleteTV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with a helper function of dp to pixels to set the correct corner radius in pixels:

```
public static int dp2px(Resources resource, int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,resource.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

and the **R.layout.custom_drop_down_item** is your custom item layout like below (with android:textAlignment="center" to center each item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1" />
```

And the Final Result will be like below:

[image: DropDownImage]